# Creating a hierarchical index from scratch

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a dataframe like this from scratch, as in I have no csv that I can read in data from.

```
          A      B      
window          
1H       0.1     1
                 2
                 3     
         0.2     1
                 2
                 3
6H       0.1     1
                 2
                 3    
         0.2     1
                 2
                 3
12H      0.1     1
                 2
                 3  
         0.2     1
                 2
                 3
24H      0.1     1
                 2
                 3     
         0.2     1
                 2
                 3
```

I've tried

```
res = pd.DataFrame(columns=['window', 'A', 'B'])
res['window'] = ['1H', '6H', '12H', '24H']
res.set_index('window', inplace=True)
res.loc['1H', 'A'] = [0.1, 0.2]
```

as a start. I also tried `res.loc['1H', 'A'] = pd.Series([0.1, 0.2]).` It doesn't work. What can I do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have `MultiIndex`

```
idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['1H', '6H', '12H', '24H'],[0.1,0.2],[1,2,3]],names=['Windows', 'A','B'])
```